# Why is this setState function working abnormally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I added a timer variable in state to change every second by 1
Why is it is rendering with 2,4,6,.. every second rather than 1,2,3,.. and how to imporove it ?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class UseRefTimer extends Component {

interval

constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
         timer:0
    }
}

componentDidMount(){
     this.interval = setInterval(()=>{
         this.setState( prev => (this.state.timer = prev.timer + 1))
     },1000)
}


componentWillUnmount(){
    clearInterval(this.interval)
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            Time : {this.state.timer} 
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

export default UseRefTimer

Comment: You really should use useEffect

Comment: @epascarello You can't use hooks in class components.

Comment: Because you are mutating the state with the `=` operator, and you are probably using React in Strict Mode, which causes the `setState` callback to run twice for every `setState` call. You need to stop mutating the state.

Comment: @JLRishe Thanks and will remember not to change state by = .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mutating `this.state.timer`. You should just return the next state instead:

```
this.setState( prev => ({timer: prev.timer + 1}));
```

The reason you see the state being incremented by `2` is [strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects). In strict mode `setState` gets called twice to detect unintended side effects. Updater functions should be pure (side-effect-free):

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it
> can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic.
> This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:
>
> - Class component `constructor`, `render`, and `shouldComponentUpdate` methods
> - Class component static `getDerivedStateFromProps` method
> - Function component bodies
> - **State updater functions (the first argument to
>   `setState`)**
> - Functions passed to `useState`, `useMemo`, or `useReducer`

Comment: Can you give me the reason why it increases by 2?

Comment: @MayankJaiswal Most likely you are using react [strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects) which helps finding unintended side effects like yours. In strict mode state updated are called twice.